# How do I fit my background in my website?

Tags: html, css, web

This is my code in index.html (header)

```
<header id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col">
                   <div class="banner text-center">
                       <h1 class="display-1 text-capitalize w50 mx-auto">
                          <small>Welcome</small> <strong class="primary-color">The Rosa </strong>
                       </h1>

                       <a href="" class=btn main-btn my-4 text-capitalize"> Order Online </a>

                   </div>
               </div> 
            </div>
        </div>




        <a href="" class="btn header-link primary-color"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
    </header>
```

And this is in main.css

```
.sub-headline{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8.5rem;
    font-family: 'Herr Von Muellerhoff', cursive;
    color: #c59d5f;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: .4;
    margin-top: 200 px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.first-letter{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10.3rem;
}
.display-1{
    color: black;
    font-size:3.7rem;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: .5rem;
}
```

This is how I am trying to insert the background:

```
  #header{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(../img/main-background-xs.jpg)
}
```

But my image which is:[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAngA.jpg) is not appearing the way I want, but it appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxovt.jpg):

Ps: This will be just the first page of my website, when I will scroll down I want to have different backgrounds.

Comment: Please post all significant html code.

Comment: I edited @WoAiNii

Comment: which way do you want it to appear?

Comment: I want the full image to appear. @loicEzt

Comment: @HANA  you want it to take up the whole frame ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want @loicEzt

Answer (score 0):

Add **background-size:100% 100%;** to header div.

Comment: Tested here with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/StangaciuGeorge/jxs72dqv/

Comment: You should not use this. it will cause some heavy distorsion depending on the screen size.

Comment: @loicEzt I think will not. Depending on the row height which is set anyway before, the image will fit perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the background to the body if you want it to take up the whole frame

```
body{
   background:url('your-image-url') ;
}
```

Comment: The whole frame of this section? Well not in the body

Comment: As I said in ps:"This will be just the first page of my website, when I will scroll down I want to have different backgrounds." so..

Comment: @HANA then add `background-repeat:no-repeat;` so the background will only display once on the top of your page